# creating app with dynamic IP address

Tags: .net, vb.net, dynamic-ip

I am trying to access VB.Net exe on a client system through LAN.Its working fine for server with static IP address.In case I try to access it with server having dynamic IP address, It doesn't provide access(config file containing server name).
how can do it with dynamic ip address?

Answer (score 1):

Register for an account at http://www.dyndns.com/ and install the proper application. Set the server name in the application so that dyndns will resolve your dynamic IP to that name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to access server by hostname using [Dns.GetHostAddresses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx) method.